# Linear programming with non-zero constraints?

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming

I'm trying to find references for a linear programming problem where the variables $x_i$ we are searching for have to be above certain thresholds $d_i$.

So that the expression of the problem is:

*maximize:* $\textbf{c}^{T}\textbf{x}$

*subject to:* $\textbf{A}\textbf{x} \leq \textbf{b}$

*and* $\textbf{x}\geq \textbf{d}$  *with* $d_i > 0$

As opposed to the canonical form:

*maximize:* $\textbf{c}^{T}\textbf{x}$

*subject to:* $\textbf{A}\textbf{x} \leq \textbf{b}$

*and* $\textbf{x}\geq 0 $

Does changing the last constraint from $\textbf{x}\geq 0 $  to $\textbf{x}\geq \textbf{d}$ change anything in the problem? I assume it does, but I can't find any reference to how to approach it?

Comment: This constraint can also be modelled in the $A$ and $b$ parameters, since you can make a row get something like $-x_i \leq -d_i$, which is the same as $x_i \geq d_i$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $u=x-d$ or equivalently $x=u+d$.  Then your problem can be written as

$\max_{u} c^{T}u+c^{T}d$

subject to

$Au \leq b+Ad$

$u\geq 0$.

Comment: wait just confirming, should it be Au <= b + Ad or Au <= b - Ad

Comment: also since d is known (like b is known), then isn't it just max_u of c_transpose * u